# Getting choices from choice field in Online using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, jsom

I am trying to get all of the choices from a choice site column in SharePoint online. Using the following code I get to the success method but it errors out saying 'field' is undefined. I don't understand why this doesn't work because I have defined field in the fields() method

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    function fields() {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);

        var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
        var web = appContextSite.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var siteColumns = web.get_fields();
        var field = context.castTo(siteColumns.getByInternalNameOrTitle('InternalFieldName'), SP.FieldChoice);

        context.load(field);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
    }

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
        var choices = field.get_choices();
        alert("Choices: (" + choices.length + ") - " + choices.join(", "));
    }

    function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

function fields() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);

    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    context.load(web);

    var field = ctx.castTo(web.get_availableFields().getByTitle('fieldTitle'), SP.FieldChoice);
    //var field = context.castTo(siteColumns.getByInternalNameOrTitle('InternalFieldName'), SP.FieldChoice);

    context.load(field);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod,onFailureMethod);
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    var choices = field.get_choices();
    alert("Choices: (" + choices.length + ") - " + choices.join(", "));
}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error

Comment: try again with updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can also try REST API using following code

`var appwebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
var requestUrl = appwebUrl + "/_api/web/AvailableFields?$filter=InternalName eq 'InternalName'";
$.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var fields = data.d.results;
                var choices = fields[0].Choices.results;

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Failed to load field');
            }
        });`